# C# MVC Ajax result undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Ajax function which populates some fields in a popup form for me, but when I run the code the fields in the form aren't filled and I don't get any errors.

When I start debugging I can see that my controller getting the data I require from the database.

My controller:

```
 public class KlantController : Controller
    {
        //private IRepository repository;
        private IRepository empDB;
        public KlantController(IRepository klantRepository)
        {
            this.empDB = klantRepository;
        }
        //public ViewResult List()
        //{
        //    return View(repository.GetAllKlanten);
        //}

        // GET: Home  
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult List()
        {
            return Json(empDB.GetAllKlanten, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public JsonResult Add(Klant emp)
        {
            return Json(empDB.KlantToevoegen(emp), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

//this is the part where I get the required data to fill the form. I can see that the value "Emplyee" is filled.
        public JsonResult GetbyID(int ID)
        {
            var Employee = empDB.GetAllKlanten.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(ID));
            return Json(Employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public JsonResult Update(Klant emp)
        {
            return Json(empDB.KlantToevoegen(emp), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        //public JsonResult Delete(int ID)
        //{
        //    return Json(empDB.Delete(ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //}
    }
```

The data I extract from the data base should be used here:

```
//Function for getting the Data Based upon Klant ID  
function getbyID(EmpID) {
    $('#Voornaam').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#Achternaam').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#Adres').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#Postcode').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $.ajax({
        url: "getbyID/" + EmpID,
        typr: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) { <- I can see the data in result
            $('#Id').val(result.Id); <- but in "Id" there is nothing and says result.Id undefined
            $('#Voornaam').val(result.Voornaam);
            $('#Achternaam').val(result.Achternaam);
            $('#Adres').val(result.Adres);
            $('#Postcode').val(result.Postcode);

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#btnUpdate').show();
            $('#btnAdd').hide();
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I have no clue what to do and how to get the data where I want. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: try to put these at first `$('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#btnUpdate').show();
            $('#btnAdd').hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method returns an IEnumerable not a single record.  Try changing the method to get the first record or iterate the results in the JavaScript

Comment: Hmm that sounds about right. How do u suggest I use the IEnumerable in the javascript code?
But when I inspect 'result' with the debugger all the info is there.

Comment: Check the length of result to ensure you have a record and then use index notation to access the members of the first record, result[0].Id

Comment: Nice the [0] after result did the trick! Thanks you very much :)